# Make multiple divs of equal height when they aren't always on the same line

Tags: html, css

I've tried a bit and am having trouble with this.

I have 6 `div`s with headings and lists. Ideally, I'd like to have these line up as required, with a maximum of 3 one any one line, so the potential layouts are either 3x2, 2x3 or 6x1.

The problem I've having at the moment is that I can't get the divs to match their heights correctly.

Issues I've had:

- I can't use `display:table-cell` as this means I have fixed rows.
- I tried using fixed heights, but that causes odd offsets as in the second image.

I've got a [jsfiddle setup with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/VNcaH/) but its below as well.

### How can I (preferably with CSS only) get these `div`s to have identical heights and widths, while lining up vertically correctly?

CSS (generated from LESS, sans `ul` and `h2` styling):

```
div div {
        display:inline-block; 
        border:1px solid gray;
        padding:5px;
        margin:10px;
        width:20%;
        height:100%;
        border-radius: 8px;
}
h2 {
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
    font-size:12pt;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="homeFaq">

    <div>
        <h2>What is metadata?</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>What is [BRAND]?</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>How can I get data?</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>How can I add content?</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Lorum Lorum?</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Lorum Lorum?</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum</li>
            <li>Ipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: 2 rows of 3 with unequal heights]

[image: 2 rows of 3 with unequal heights]

[image: 2 rows of 4 and 2 still unequal heights]

[image: 3 rows of 2 with more unequal heights]

http://jsfiddle.net/VNcaH/

Comment: y didn't you use float ? AND MIN HEIGHT ?

Comment: try this, add in `h2 {min-height: 40px;}` and `ul {min-height:120px;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fix height and vertical align top as below

```
div div {
        display:inline-block; 
        border:1px solid gray;
        padding:5px;
        margin:10px;
        width:20%;
        height:150px;
        border-radius: 8px;
    vertical-align:top;
};
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VNcaH/5/)

Comment: This is probably the more correct one and I've implemented it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

updated js fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/VNcaH/4/

You can use `min-height` value in your `h2` and `ul` tags.it will be fine working fine !!!

```
div div h2 {
  min-height: 30px;
} 
div div ul {
  min-height:80px;
}
```

Comment: I did some tweaking to the eventual code, but this worked. not sure why. Damn CSS. For reference, it only needed the `min-height` on the heading for when it wrapped onto a new line.

Comment: but I think it still have offset top problem.